# Conan failing to upload package when --all is specified

Tags: c++, jenkins, conan

I have a Jenkins/Conan build that has been working for a year.  All of a sudden, it is failing to upload the binary package when "conan upload" is executed.  However, it still uploads the recipe.

**New output:**

```
NetworkKernel/1.0.0@XXX/testing: Package 'cc8b57af37a13f1b22ee796d76b2fcf820a31cb8' created

conan upload NetworkKernel/1.0.0@XXX/testing -r=XXX--all --force --confirm --retry 20 --retry-wait 30 

Uploading NetworkKernel/1.0.0@XXX/testing to remote 'XXX'

Uploading conanmanifest.txt                                           

Uploading conanfile.py                                                

Uploading conan_sources.tgz                                           
Uploaded conan recipe 'NetworkKernel/1.0.0@XXX/testing' to 'XXX': https://example.com/artifactory/api/conan/XXX-CONAN
```

**Old output:**

```
Uploading NetworkKernel/1.1.0@XXX/testing to remote 'XXX'

Compressing recipe sources...                                         
Uploading conanmanifest.txt                                           


Uploading conanfile.py                                                


Uploading conan_sources.tgz                                           

Uploaded conan recipe 'NetworkKernel/1.1.0@XXX/testing' to 'xxx': https://example.com/artifactory/api/conan/XXX-CONAN
Uploading package 1/1: cc8b57af37a13f1b22ee796d76b2fcf820a31cb8

Compressing package...                                                
Requesting upload permissions...                                      
Requesting upload permissions...Done!                                 

Uploading conanmanifest.txt                                           


Uploading conaninfo.txt                                               


Uploading conan_package.tgz
```

Windows OS
Artifactory version: 5.9.7
Conan version: 1.0.0

As you can see, it is only uploading the recipe even thought --all is specified (and the package is successfully created).  I think someone messed with the build machine, but I can't figure out what has changed.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Which Conan version are you running? Are running Conan server or Artifactory, which version?  Which OS?

Comment: It seems that your ``--all`` is together to the remote, like ``-r=XXX--all``, no spaces, it might be being skipped. If this is still an issue, I strongly suggest submitting an issue report to https://github.com/conan-io/conan, there is better suited for bug reports, regressions, feature-requests.